# Sequence of dates by each next 15th or last day of month

Tags: r, date, seq

I have start and end dates as e.g. 03-05-2014 and 01-07-2014. I would like to create a code so that it would output sequences such as next 15th of each month or next end day of the month, in this case 15-05-2014 & 15-06-2014, or 31-05-2014 and 31-06-2014.

I know this would be possible by creating sequence of days and then identifying the particular day (at least for the 1st case) as in `seq(1st date, 2nd date, by = "day")`, but let's just say that for computational limitations this is not possible - I have to create it for many years and millions of records which need to be grouped as well.

Is there any workaround there?

Comment: Just use the `som` function in the link `+14`. `eom` gives you what you want. Also google "R first last day of month" for heeps of other ways (including the `lubridate` alternatives posted here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start <- as.Date("2014-05-03")
end <- as.Date("2014-07-01")

library(lubridate)
floor_date(seq(start, end, by = 'month'), unit = "month") + 14
ceiling_date(seq(start, end, by = 'month'), unit = "month")-1
```

Sequence by the month and use `floor_date` from the `lubridate` package to start at the beginning of the month.

Comment: This can give dates that are outside the `start` to `end` range.

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = as.Date("03-05-2014", "%d-%m-%Y")
d2 = as.Date("01-07-2014", "%d-%m-%Y")

library(lubridate)
d1_p = round_date(d1, unit = "month")
d2_p = round_date(d2, unit = "month")    
mydates = seq.Date(d1_p, d2_p, "months")
mydates = mydates[mydates < d2_p]

lapply(mydates, function(x) x + 14:15)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2014-05-15" "2014-05-16"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2014-06-15" "2014-06-16"

ceiling_date(mydates, unit = "month") - 1 
#[1] "2014-05-31" "2014-06-30"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great, I've ticked the other answer only since it was shorter.